# Can't get cron job to run

Tags: php, cron

Want job to run a shell script at 39 minutes after 6PM every day:

```
   $ crontab /Users/non12/Documents/crontab.job1
   $ crontab -l
   39 18 * * * /Library/WebServer/Documents/PBS/pbscli.sh
```

Looks good to me here.
Here is the cron log reflecting the loads but no cmd/runs. Why is that?

```
   debug flags enabled: misc
   [10317] cron started
   log_it: (non12 10317) RELOAD (tabs/non12)
   log_it: (non12 10317) RELOAD (tabs/non12)
   log_it: (non12 10317) RELOAD (tabs/non12)
   log_it: (non12 10317) RELOAD (tabs/non12)
   log_it: (non12 10317) RELOAD (tabs/non12)
```

Script is executable and runs fine from terminal

The script:

```
cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/PBS
/usr/bin/php viewCLIControl.php 2> /Library/WebServer/Documents/PBS/pbs_error.log
```

Comment: have you checked if SELinux is blocking your cron job? http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/cron may be a good read.

Answer (score 1):

use the exact command as one line in cron

```
39 18 * * * cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/PBS /usr/bin/php viewCLIControl.php 2> /Library/WebServer/Documents/PBS/pbs_error.log
```

Comment: Another RELOAD but that is all I get

Answer (score 0):

Open shell and type this:

```
command="php /Library/WebServer/Documents/PBS/viewCLIControl.php 2> /Library/WebServer/Documents/PBS/pbs_error.log"
job="39 18 * * * $command"
cat <(fgrep -i -v "$command" <(crontab -l)) <(echo "$job") | crontab -
```

The above creates a cronjob that executes `/Library/WebServer/Documents/PBS/viewCLIControl.php` every day at `18.39`.